# How to assign keyboard shortcut to Source Control commands in Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, visual-studio-2005, perforce

I use Visual C++ 2008 in Visual Studio 2008.  I frequently use the following command to diff an open file against its most recent checked-in version:

```
File | Source Control | Compare...
```

I can also do the same thing by clicking on an icon in the Source Control toolbar.

I'm not certain, but I believe this command is the same for any source control plugin (I happen to use the Perforce plugin.)

I'd like to assign a keyboard shortcut to execute this command but I can't seem to find it listed anywhere in dialog where such assignments are normally made:

```
Tools | Customize... | Commands
```

Did I just not see the command in the customize dialog?  Is there another method to assign such a keyboard shortcut?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tools -> Options -> Keyboard -> Commands Containing "Compare"

Answer (score 1):

Nescio's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/188225/how-to-assign-keyboard-shortcut-to-source-control-commands-in-visual-studio-2008#188256) is on the money.  Here's a little more info:

- The shortcut assignment can be made at `Tools | Options | Environment | Keyboard`
- The command is called `File.Compare`